# Cellular structure in solid phase detonations

Tags: condensed-matter, explosions

For gaseous and liquid detonations, the detonation propagates by the energy released at the triple-points which form a cellular structure. This structure is traced using a soot foil during experiments.

In solid phase explosives such as TNT and C4, the literature is devoid of discussion about the triple-points and soot foils (both experiments and simulations). The primary method of detonation propagation is through hot-spot generation. These hot-spots are formed at imperfections such as voids, grain boundaries, slip boundaries, etc..

Does the cellular detonation structure exist in solid phase explosives? Is the lack of experimental data because of the difficulty in generating the data, or are solid-phase explosives inherently different than gaseous or liquid? Is it possible that the triple-points exist but because of the heterogeneous nature of solid explosives, they are minor or secondary methods of propagation relative to the imperfections in the mixture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some evidence that cellular structure exists in C-4 and TNT. In particular, cells in C-4 were reported by Dunne (Dunne B B 1970 *Science* 167 1124–1126) and in TNT by Howe et al. (Howe P, Frey R and Melani G 1976 *Combust. Sci. Technol*. 14 63–74).

You can find a review article (open access) I wrote that covers cellular instability in condensed phase explosives here:

http://iopscience.iop.org/1742-6596/500/5/052016